# angular2 - reusable component will not init from network call data

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with a radio control that I cant set from an edit from a database call.

My radio is a reusable component.  On my main app onInit I can set it like this and it works fine:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.model_initials.available='M';
}
```

However when I load from database the value should be set to

```
 this.model_initials.available='Q';
```

Here is how I load onInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {

//this.model_initials.available='M';
this._modelService.getModel(this.model_id)
    .subscribe(model_initials => this.model_initials = model_initials,
    null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });
```

}

I can verify that the data is properly loaded becuase on page load print the object to the page:

```
{{this.model_initials | json }}
{ "available": "Q", "horizon": 8 }
```

However the control is not set to "Q". In fact set to nothing.

But if a then click the radio it alternates between M and Q just find and can submit to a database.  So the only issue is the init of the control from data from a network call.  I am a newbie so I quite dont understand.  Is because the control is loading after the call? But I though that was ngOnInit was supposed to resolve?

Here is my HTML and typescript code for the component:

```
<radio ngModel="model_initials.available" [available]="model_initials.available" (ngModelChange)="myValueChangeRadio($event);" #available="ngForm" ngControl="available" [useForm]="true"></radio>




import {Component, OnInit,Input,Output,EventEmitter,Provider, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass,NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterLink} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

const SELECTOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => RadioFormatSelectorComponent),
    multi: true
});

@Component({
    selector: 'radio',
    template: `
    <div class="radio-inline custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" (click)="model='M'" [ngModel]="{checked: model == 'M'}" type="radio" id="yes" name="available" [ngClass]="{'form-control': useForm}">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            Monthly
        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline custom-control custom-radio">
        <label>
            <input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" (click)="model='Q'" [ngModel]="{checked: model == 'Q'}" type="radio" id="no" name="available" [ngClass]="{'form-control': useForm}">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            Quarterly
        </label>
    </div>
    `,
    directives: [NgClass],
    providers: [SELECTOR_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
}) 

export class RadioFormatSelectorComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() useForm = false;
    @Input() available:any;
    @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {}

     model: any;
     ngOnInit() {
         console.log(this.model);
         this.model = this.available;

     }

    onChange(newValue:any) {
        this.ngModelChange.emit(this.model);
    }

    onModelChange: Function = () => {};

    onModelTouched: Function = () => {};

    writeValue() : void {
        this.model;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onModelTouched = fn;
    }

}



EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 24 in [{checked: model == 'M'}=$event] in RadioFormatSelectorComponent@3:74 ("m-radio">
        <label>
            <input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" (click)="model='M'" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="{checked: model == 'M'}" type="radio" id="M" name="available" [ngClass]="{'form-control'"): RadioFormatSelectorComponent@3:74
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 24 in [{checked: model == 'Q'}=$event] in RadioFormatSelectorComponent@10:74 ("m-radio">
        <label>
            <input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" (click)="model='Q'" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="{checked: model == 'Q'}" type="radio" id="Q" name="available" [ngClass]="{'form-control'"): RadioFormatSelectorComponent@10:74
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two-way data binding you need to change this:

```
[ngModel]="{checked: model == 'M'}"
```

To this:

```
[(ngModel)]="{checked: model == 'M'}"
```

Without the paratheses you would need:

```
[ngModel]="{checked: model == 'M'}" (ngModelChange)="{checked: model == $event"}>
```

Comment: Oh, actually... I just realized that you're assigning your @Input value to another attribute... 

So if the input is asynchronously loaded from a database and it isn't available when ngInit is called on your reuseable component - then it will never get updated... 

So you probably actually want: 
    [(ngModel)]="{checked: available == 'M'}"

Comment: It worked  used your suggestion but changed model to available.  Thanks!